# Error setting 'text' property of a Matlab uicontrol using its Java handle

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface

I am using Yair Altman's [findjobj function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) to add [Java callbacks](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks) to my Matlab GUI. My goal is that each keypress inside the edittext (specifically arrow up, arrow down) changes the edittext's string to something different (increment, decrement a number).

The problem is that `set`-ting the text of the Javaobject triggers a weird Java error. 
Here is a minimal (and nonsensical) example that shows the problem:

```
function keypress_callback_test()
hf = figure();
he=uicontrol('Parent',hf,'Style','edit', 'String', '0');

jhe = findjobj(he, 'nomenu');
set(jhe,'KeyPressedCallback', @change_text);

function change_text(hObject, event)
set(hObject, 'text', num2str(rand(1)))
```

The code works, but Matlab displays the following (quite long) error message:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.getSelectionStart(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.text.PlainView.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.text.FieldView.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

What causes this error and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't figured out what caused this, but I found a workaround. You can pass additional arguments to the callback function. If I pass the Matlab handle of the edittext, I can `set` the text on that instead.

Here is the fixed example (changes are in line 5 and below):

```
function keypress_callback_test()
hf = figure();
he=uicontrol('Parent',hf,'Style','edit', 'String', '0');

jhe = findjobj(he, 'nomenu');
set(jhe,'KeyPressedCallback', {@change_text, he});


function change_text(hObject, event, he)
set(he, 'String', num2str(rand(1)))
```